# Try / Catch error_message() Fetch Multiple Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, error-handling

I have about 1000 line stored procedure that make a complex stuff , i am trying to use try , catch to get any errors , it works fine but if the script contain multiple errors  , only the last error is retrieved , so error_message() only get the last error

```
BEGIN TRY                                                           
 Begin Tran                    
       --Staff            
Commit Tran                                                          
End Try                                                                      
        BEGIN CATCH                                           
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0                                                         
     select                                                                      
     error_message() as errormessage,                                                                      
     error_number() as erronumber,                                                                      
     error_state() as errorstate,                                                                     
     error_procedure() as errorprocedure,                                                                      
     error_line() as errorline;                                                                      
            ROLLBACK                                                                      
         END CATCH
```

- Error : 1
- Error : 2
- Error : 3

the result set of the select query , return only Error : 3

Is there any way to get all error , or at least the first error which is more important to be retrieved

I have sql server 2008   ,

I google before post here and can't find any applicable solution

Comment: Insert the errors into an errorlog table. Then select all of the rows from that table before exiting the stored proc.

Comment: Very nice work around.